# System.Net.WebException HTTP status code

Tags: c#, http-status-codes, webexception

Is there an easy way to get the HTTP status code from a `System.Net.WebException`?

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Maybe something like this...

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        var response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        if (response != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HTTP Status Code: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
        }
        else
        {
            // no http status code available
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // no http status code available
    }
}
```

Comment: but in case of "connectfailure" exception of webexception i get response as null, in that case how can i get the httpstatus code

Comment: @rusty: You can't. If there's a connection failure then there is no HTTP status code to be got.

Comment: If the error is a ProtocolError, you don't have to check the response for null. See the comment in the example on this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es54hw8e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @AndrasToth But tools like ReSharper will give you a warning if you omit the null-check. And in any case, it's good practise to code defensively.

Comment: @TomLint I don't think it's about warnings or defensive coding, it's that @LukeH is using the `as` operator, which is a dynamic cast, so the check for null is to see if the cast has worked or not, at runtime.

Comment: @ympostor I know, but there are people who just assume the cast just works. And oftentimes it does, depending on the situation. The null-check gives you ensurance that your assumption was actually correct, and prevents unexpected exceptions should the cast fail.

Comment: How get ***HTTP Substatus*** value ? For example, _404.13 Content Length Too Large Reference_: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/

Answer (score 32):

By using the [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) (`?.`) you can get the HTTP status code with a single line of code:

```
 HttpStatusCode? status = (ex.Response as HttpWebResponse)?.StatusCode;
```

The variable `status` will contain the [`HttpStatusCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx). When the there is a more general failure like a network error where no HTTP status code is ever sent then `status` will be null. In that case you can inspect `ex.Status` to get the [`WebExceptionStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you just want a descriptive string to log in case of a failure you can use the [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) (`??`) to get the relevant error:

```
string status = (ex.Response as HttpWebResponse)?.StatusCode.ToString()
    ?? ex.Status.ToString();
```

If the exception is thrown as a result of a 404 HTTP status code the string will contain "NotFound". On the other hand, if the server is offline the string will contain "ConnectFailure" and so on.

> (And for anybody that wants to know how to get the HTTP substatus
>   code. That is not possible. It is a Microsoft IIS concept that is only
>   logged on the server and never sent to the client.)

Comment: Not sure whether the `?.` operator was originally named null propagation operator or null-conditional operator during preview release. But Atlassian resharper gives a warning to use null propagation operator in such scenarios. Nice to know that it is also called null-conditional operator.

Comment: A bit late to this party, but fair warning that the null-conditional operator is a C# 6.0 feature, so one needs to be using a compiler that supports it. [Stack Overflow answer with further details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089426/how-to-install-the-ms-c-sharp-6-0-compiler).  VS 2015+ has it by default, but if one is using any kind of build/deploy environment other than just "their machine", other things might need to be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 18):

(I do realise the question is old, but it's among the top hits on Google.)

A common situation where you want to know the response code is in exception handling. As of C# 7, you can use pattern matching to actually only enter the catch clause if the exception matches your predicate:

```
catch (WebException ex) when (ex.Response is HttpWebResponse response)
{
     doSomething(response.StatusCode)
}
```

This can easily be extended to further levels, such as in this case where the `WebException` was actually the inner exception of another (and we're only interested in `404`):

```
catch (StorageException ex) when (ex.InnerException is WebException wex && wex.Response is HttpWebResponse r && r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
```

Finally: note how there's no need to re-throw the exception in the catch clause when it doesn't match your criteria, since we don't enter the clause in the first place with the above solution.

Answer (score 10):

this works only if WebResponse is a HttpWebResponse.

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (System.Net.WebException exc)
{
    var webResponse = exc.Response as System.Net.HttpWebResponse;
    if (webResponse != null && 
        webResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("401");
    }
    else
        throw;
}
```

Comment: why only deal with 401-Unauthorized instead of all possible HTTP error status codes? this is the worst answer

Comment: @ympostor This is just an example. Any reasonable developer understands this. Your comment is the most thoughtless I've ever read here.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this code to get HTTP status code from WebException. It works in Silverlight too because SL does not have WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError defined.

```
HttpStatusCode GetHttpStatusCode(WebException we)
{
    if (we.Response is HttpWebResponse)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
        return response.StatusCode;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `return 0` ? or better `HttpStatusCode?` (***nullable***)?

Comment: Will this work? `var code = GetHttpStatusCode(ex);    if (code != HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) {EventLog.WriteEntry(   EventLog.WriteEntry("MyApp", code, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information, 1);}`

Comment: I can't understand what you wanted to do in this sample. In what cases you wanted event to be logged?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is but if there was such a property it wouldn't be considered reliable.  A `WebException` can be fired for reasons other than HTTP error codes including simple networking errors.  Those have no such matching http error code.

Can you give us a bit more info on what you're trying to accomplish with that code.  There may be a better way to get the information you need.