# Response.Status from myWebClient.UploadFile

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm uploading a file using this code:

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(string.Format("http://{0}/WebApplication/Default.aspx", this.WebServerName), "POST", filePath);
```

I receive the file in `Page_Load()` :

```
foreach (string f in Request.Files.AllKeys)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[f];
    Utils.ProcessUpload(file);
    Response.Status = "success";
}
```

I would like to read the status from `responseArray` so I can make a decision based on the uploads status. I'm not figuring out how to get the `Status` from the `responseArray`.

**EDIT**: The example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/esst63h0(v=vs.100).aspx) doesn't provide much help. it does display the response array

Answer (score 0):

In responseArray is only body of the response not the status and headers you are interesting on. You can be sure that if UploadFile method returns status will be success 2xx or others. If response will be 4xx (error) than WebException is thrown and you can read status from exception:

[Check this link how to handle this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3614096/373249)

If you want more precise status handling, you have to use WebRequest / WebResponse directly.