# how to access exception.Response.StatusCode variable in the try with block

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception, f#

As I'm debugging, I noticed $exception within the locals window as a result of an exception thrown implying this variable is available in the scope.

The question is how can I access this $exception variable.

How can line 78 be?

```
| x ->  Debug.WriteLine("exception" + $exception.Response.StatusCode)
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch exceptions of a specific type with this syntax:

```
try
  ...
with
| :? System.Net.WebException as e ->
    let response = e.Response :> System.Net.HttpWebResponse
    Console.WriteLine("exception" + response.StatusCode)
```

Note you need to cast `WebException.Response` to `System.Net.HttpWebResponse` so you can access its `StatusCode` property.

See [the MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/exception-handling/the-try-with-expression) for more.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the case to `HttpWebResponse` can fail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614034/system-net-webexception-http-status-code